# Mininet not connecting to OpenDayLight

Tags: sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I am trying to connect my custom topology to the ODL controller using the command:

```
sudo mn --custom topology.py --topo mytopo --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=6633
```

However on running this command, I get a line as :

```
Unable to contact the remote controller at 127.0.0.1:6633
```

When I do pingall, all the packets are dropped. How do I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try adding this flag to your 'mn' command to make it use openflow v1.3. I think
by default it's using v1.0

```
--switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

also, just to be complete, what feature(s) have you installed?

Comment: I think all the features are installed. I tried installing some features as recommended by some websites. But as I entered the command feature:----, the command line returned immediately. I think it has all features installed.

Comment: but, which features exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the IP address in your command to your public IP address. (You can type `ifconfig` on your terminal or just Google "my ip address" to figure that out.)

If that doesn't work, can you clarify what system you are running Mininet on and what configuration you have for Mininet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command:

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=(SDN IP)
```